Picture copied from Paint.NET and inserted from clipboard on Firefox was shifted by some pixels
I asked a question and I inserted a picture from the clipboard. It became uploaded as

while it should look like

After saving the image to disk and uploading the image from the file, it worked fine.
Can we fix this? I often don't want to save images before posting them to SO.
My editor is Paint.NET 5.0.12. The image inserts nicely in Word.
My browser is Firefox 123.0 (64 bit) and my OS is Windows 10 22H2 (19045.4046).
It doesn't happen with Chrome 122.0.6261.70.

I'm not sure if this is seem something controlled by SO in any way.

Seems like barely an issue. Sure, the image probably gets wrongly transformed but...I can't think of any instance where this would really cause a problem. It's barely few columns of pixels. If it was something like 100 pixel columns then it'd be an issue. but also, I suspect we'd have had a lot of reports if this happened with such magnitude and any regularity.

@yivi: the image inserts fine in any other program like Word. So it's not a problem of Paint.NET which I'm using as the image editor.

@VLAZ: Sure, we can ignore the problem. This should not be the attitude of programmers, just IMHO. If there's a bug, I fix it. But yeah, I see a lot of software where bugs like that are just ignored. Maybe SO is one of them. In that case I will think about whether I still want to contribute here.

Seems like a valid bug to me, even though the impact may be minor. May be worth stating browser/OS and if you've used the new editor (discussions/SO Teams) or the old one, for reproducibility.

@ThomasWeller I'm saying that the impact of it seems extremely low. Your bug report seems to imply it's much higher.

@VLAZ: I'm not a native speaker. Which of my words imply a high severity or high urgency? IMHO I am just stating facts.

@ThomasWeller "I often don't want to save images before posting them to SO." - I don't think you have to. Both as "it's not mandatory" and also "even if the bug manifests, it seems it's not really an issue worth trying to get a workaround to".

This is most likely a bug in either the editor or the browser and not a bug with Stack Overflow. See: https://forums.getpaint.net/topic/124628-1-px-line-on-top-of-every-image-pasted-into-firefox-from-paintnet/

Does this issue still occur now that Stack Exchange images are no longer hosted on Imgur?

Small bugs often point to fundamental flaws that affect the entire system. They shouldn't be ignored.

@PM2Ring: it happened again just 2 days ago

I'm reopening this because it's about pasting images into Stack Overflow on a supported browser, and topicality should be able to be determined entirely from the question without needing to know the answer.  It's also possible that this answer is wrong, or that Stack Overflow could somehow address it; both of these could merit additional answers.

This appears to be a bug with the image editor (Paint.NET) in combination with Firefox, when used for images in the edit window, and not one that Stack Overflow has any control over.

If by editor you are referring to my comment I meant "Paint.NET" (the image editor) by editor. You'll basically face this issue even on other sites when you use Paint.NET and Firefox together. Although there might be things that the site could do to work around the issue so IMO it should be okay to keep this question open.

Direct link to the firefox bug report which can be found in a getpaint link posted in a comment under the question: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1436969 . It seems to describe this exact problem.
